# Yum install of home-made RPM giving error

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, yum, rhel

I am trying to isntall something using "yum install my.rpm"

The problem is I am getting

```
TypeError: an integer is required
error: python callback <bound method RPMTransaction.callback of <yum.rpmtrans.RPMTransaction instance at 0x013e3f8>> failed, aborting!
```

What does this mean? I turned on verbosity of the yum install, cant figure anything out. This is RHEL 6.1

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the spec file you used?

Comment: I can't post the spec file - were you looking for anything in particular in it?

Comment: What happens when you run "rpm -Uvh my.rpm"? Also, what is the output of "rpm -qp --scripts my.rpm" and of "rpm -qip my.rpm"?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I am having the same problem today.

Comment: I solved it (for me.)  I was installing the package using `sudo` from a root-squash mounted NFS home directory... I moved it to /tmp and installed it just fine. YMMV

Answer (score 8):

If rpm is not able to access the file for some reason while installing the package, it throws this error.

For example if your rpm is located on a NFS share witn  `root_squash` directive, and try to install, then since root while attempting to access the file won't be permitted to it will fail, and it throws this excact error.

If this is your case, then putting the rpm in something like `/tmp` first, and then re-trying will solve it.

Comment: I had this exact problem and this answer solved it for me.  Such an arcane error message...

Answer (score -1):

To install a rpm file with yum, you need to use the localinstall command:

> localinstall
>       Is  used  to  install  a set of local rpm files. If required the enabled repositories will be used to resolve dependencies. Note that
>   the install command will do a local install, if given a filename.

For example "yum localinstall my.rpm". But I think you also have a problem with your spec file.

Comment: it says as your last sentence that the install command does a local install if given a file name

Comment: You do not need to say `localinstall`, as yum will figure this out.